# $f(z)$ is of the form $\alpha z+\beta,$ where $\alpha,\beta,z$ are complex numbers,$|\alpha|\neq|\beta|$

Tags: complex-numbers

$f(z)$ is of the form $\alpha z+\beta,$ where $\alpha,\beta,z$ are complex numbers,$|\alpha|\neq|\beta|$,$f(z)$ satisfies the following properties
$(i)$If imaginary part of $z$ is non-zero,then $f(z)+\overline{f(z)}=f(\bar{z})+\overline{f(\bar{z})}$
$(ii)$If real part of $z$ is zero,then $f(z)+\overline{f(z)}=0$.
$(iii)$If $z$ is real then $f(z)\overline{f(z)}>(z+1)^2\hspace{1 cm}\forall z\in R$
$Q(1)\frac{4x^2}{(f(1)-f(-1))^2}+\frac{y^2}{(f(0))^2}=1,x,y\in R$ will represent 
$(A)$hyperbola$(B)$circle$(C)$ellipse$(D)$pair of line

---

Using the $(i)$,i could find that $\alpha=\bar{\alpha}$,that means $\alpha$ is real.
Using the $(ii)$,i could find that $\beta+\bar{\beta}=0$,that means $\beta$ is purely imaginary.
Using $(iii)$,$\alpha^2z^2+|\beta|^2>z^2+2z+1$
But i am stuck now.Please help me.Thanks

Comment: There are several unrelated questions here, and it would be advisable to divide it into separate posts.

Comment: Please dont downvote,i have removed the second part.Please help me solve this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Evaluate $f(1), f(-1)$ and $f(0)$ in terms of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ and use what you already found out. Spoiler contains exactly that and leaves the last step to you.

> $$\frac{4x^2}{(f(1)-f(-1))^2}+\frac{y^2}{(f(0))^2}=\\= \frac{4x^2}{(\alpha+\beta - (-\alpha+\beta))^2}+\frac{y^2}{\beta^2}\\= \frac{4x^2}{(2\alpha)^2}+\frac{y^2}{-\mathrm{Im}(\beta)^2}\\= \frac{x^2}{\alpha^2}-\frac{y^2}{\mathrm{Im}(\beta)^2}=1$$
>  
>  In the 3rd line I used that $\beta$ is purely imaginary and since you know that $\alpha$ is real, this represents...

Comment: @VinodKumarPunia You deleted your comment where you asked about the now deleted second part of your question, but I'll answer anyway: Since this question is finished and looks quite clean right now, I think it's best to open a new question for anything else. Also, I don't have much time right now so you'll get a quicker response from someone else by doing that. :)